# Cannot strip newline from Cocoa NSMutableString 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, newline, nsmutablestring

Hey, for the life of me, this is not working:..

```
NSMutableString *b64String = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [string _base64Encoding:string]] autorelease];

    [b64String stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"(%@)", b64String);

    NSRange foundRange = [b64String rangeOfString:@"\n"];
    if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
        [b64String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"
                                            withString:@""
                                               options:0 
                                                 range:foundRange];
    NSLog(@"(%@)", b64String);
```

Both those methods I found on SO - and they don't seem to work... I've got to be doing something terribly wrong. But, if I break on the NSLog's, I can clearly see the "\n" in the string (in the debugger AND in the console out)

Also, this is true:

```
if (foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
```

And I can see if execute the stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString method...

Comment: You mean a Cocoa NSMutableString. Objective-C is the language; NSMutableString comes from the Cocoa *framework*. Your question would would not be much different in another language (e.g., Ruby or Python), but it would be completely irrelevant to another framework (e.g., .NET or Python standard library).

Comment: Thanks Peter for the correction. Updated OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call

```
b64String = [b64String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]
```

is enough (remember to `-release` unnecessary copies of `b64string`. You may want to store it into another variable), or use the actual mutable method with full range:

```
[b64String replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [b64String length])];
```

In `-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`, the `range` parameter specifies the range where the replacement occurs. That means nothing will get replaced outside of the range. In your code, you pass the range of the 1st appearance of `\n`. The effect is only 1 occurrence of `\n` will be removed.

The `stringBy...` methods are for immutable strings. They will not modify the input string. Instead, they create a copy of the immutable string and return the modified copy.

Comment: Doesn't work - 
    [b64String stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"(%@)", b64String);

The "\n" is still there ...

Comment: @Mr-sk: See the update. Your `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` has problem too, see the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the method `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` returns a new string instead of modifying the current one.

```
NSString* trimmedString = [b64String stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks guys - should have slowed down a little to read. heh

Answer (score 0):

You can trim newlines from a `NSMutableString` in-place, but you need to use the [CFStringTrim](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542426-cfstringtrim?language=objc) method from Core Foundation.

**Objective-C:**

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"\nfoo bar baz\n"];
CFStringTrim((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)string, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"\n");
```

**Swift:**

```
let string = NSMutableString(string: "\nfoo bar baz\n")
CFStringTrim(string as CFMutableString, "\n" as CFString)
```